# Why my network needs so many epochs to give reasonable accuracy?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I have a simple network with a few layers, I tried to reduce the layers (and the num_outputs) to speed the model, but the accuracy decreased as well
my question is how to speed the convergence and enhance the accuracy at the same time. Is there something wrong in the implementation that makes the network too slow

```
learning_rate=0.99
n_x=50
n_y=10
lossList=[]
g_tb = tf.Graph()
#
with g_tb.as_default():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_x], name="x")#Glove Vectors
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_y], name="y")#scores
    with tf.name_scope('Neural_Nt'):
        fully_connected1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=x, num_outputs=500, 
                                                         activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,scope="Fully_Conn1")
        fully_connected2 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=fully_connected1, num_outputs=400, 
                                                             activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,scope="Fully_Conn2")
        fully_connected3 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=fully_connected2, num_outputs=300, 
                                                             activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,scope="Fully_Conn3")
        fully_connected4 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=fully_connected2, num_outputs=50, 
                                                             activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,scope="Fully_Conn4")
        fully_connected5 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=fully_connected2, num_outputs=10, 
                                                             activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,scope="Fully_Conn5")
        prediction = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=fully_connected3, num_outputs=10, 
                                               activation_fn=tf.nn.softmax,scope="Out")
    with tf.name_scope('Cost'):
        cost = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=y, logits=prediction,scope="Cost_Function")
    with tf.name_scope('Accuracy'):
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1, name="Argmax_Pred"), tf.argmax(y, 1, name="Y_Pred"), 
                                      name="Correct_Pred")
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32, name="Cast_Corr_Pred"), name="Accuracy")
 #       
    with tf.name_scope('Optimization'):
        optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate, name="Optimizer").minimize(cost)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
  #  


# Start session
with tf.Session(graph=g_tb) as sess:
#
    lossList=[]

    sess.run(init)
    #Save the graph in the summary
    #summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path, graph=tf.get_default_graph())
    training_epochs = 2000#4000
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        _, c ,prediction1,acc= sess.run([optimizer, cost,prediction,accuracy], feed_dict={x: np.array(gloveVectors),
                                                     y: np.array(scores)})
    # For every epoch save cost and accuracy
        print(epoch, c)
        lossList.append(c)
    print(acc)
```

Answer (score 0):

writing here my 5 cents because I can't comment.
So for starters you have a very high learning rate`learning_rate=0.99`.If you pick a high learning rate your model might learn faster but the trade off is a suboptimal set of weights or bad accuracy. You can read more about the learning rate [here.](https://machinelearningmastery.com/learning-rate-for-deep-learning-neural-networks/)

Another possibility to increase the learning speed is to increase the batch size. But be aware if you choose a very high batch size the numbers of weight updates decreases, so you might get also a bad accuracy score.

Finally you can try *Dropout Layer* between your normal layers. This can decrease the learning speed, improve the accuracy and also prevent overfitting. You can read more about Dropout [here.](https://machinelearningmastery.com/dropout-for-regularizing-deep-neural-networks/)

As far as I can see there is nothing inherently wrong with your implementation, but to be sure you can share the data you use to check again.

I hope this helps:)